# SQL: MAX of summing the values of 2 columns

Tags: mysql

so I have a table "records" like this:

```
name     month     year
Rafael   9         2018
Rafael   5         2018
Rafael   10        2017
```

And I want to get my last records (Rafael, 9, 2018). I thought about summing the month and the year and getting the max of that sum like this:

```
select * from records, max(month + year) as max_date
```

But doesn't seem to be right. Thanks for help

Comment: I'm not seeing the logic by which you pull out the `(Rafael, 5, 2018)` record.  Can you explain the logic behind your intended query?

Comment: Shouldn't you be wanting (Rafael,9,2018)?

Comment: @SEarle1986 my bad, sorry

Comment: by the way if you sum `9 + 2018` or `10 + 2017` the results are the same!

Comment: What do you want is not so clear, so, maybe you are looking at this query:

`SELECT TOP 1 * FROM  records`

Comment: @Simo damn, you're right

Comment: You will have to use LIMIT 1 as it is mysql

Comment: Hm, I thought you mean by "last" the latest (based on the year and month) record and not the first line in the record table.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean the output of the follwing?

```
select *
from records
order by year desc, month desc
limit 1
```

In general, it would be more useful to use one DATE or DATETIME column type for this purpose where you can extract year and month if you want.

Comment: need to add DESC in order by

Comment: People will have downvoted because the answer was incorrect. You're supposed to follow up a downvote with a comment. I held back from the vote and just made the comment

Answer (score 2):

Using [ORDER BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) clause, you can get the highest year and month combo. Try the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM records
ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: this is a nice variant but i prefer to use TOP. becuase I'm pretty sure he wants the top 1 and not the highest year and month combo. But the PO is not so clear about what he wants. upvote for you!

Comment: _i prefer to use TOP..._ the TOP clause works on MSSQL server. @Simo

Comment: LIMIT 1 == TOP 1

Comment: @SEarle1986 i know

Answer (score 0):

Use concat if you want to concat max month and max year

```
    Select name ,concat (concat( max(month), '-'),max(year)) from records
    Group by name
```

but if you want just year wise max year date information then use below

```
Select * from records
     order by year desc
     limit 1
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sqQz1WEEAukoWEWkbxBYxe/0

```
name    month   year
Rafael   9      2018
```